# PostgreSQL: Syntax error at or near "||"

Tags: postgresql

I am creating function which return the select query result from it. The details as shown below in the example:

**Example**:

```
Create or replace function fun_test(cola text,colb text,rel text)
returns table(columna text,columnb text)as 
$Body$
Declare
table_name varchar :='Table_';
Begin
table_name := table_name || rel;

    return query select distinct || quote_ident(cola) ||,||quote_ident(colb)|| from || quote_ident(table_name) ;

end;
$Body$
language plpgsql;
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "||"
LINE 10: ...| quote_ident(cola) ||,||quote_ident(colb)|| from || quote_i...
                                                              ^
```

Comment: Oops, it looks like you reposted it to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/69417/7788. Please delete the duplicate.

Comment: @CraigRinger, Yup! Deleted successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to construct a query dynamically, but you're not using `EXECUTE`. That won't work. You can't just put arbitrary expressions in place of identifiers, like:

> ```
> return query select distinct || quote_ident(cola) ||,||quote_ident(colb)|| from || quote_ident(table_name) ;
> ```

which is why you're getting the error at:

```
from ||
     ^
```

as that's syntactically invalid nonsense.

Instead I think you want:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select distinct ' || quote_ident(cola) ||', '||quote_ident(colb)||' from '|| quote_ident(table_name);
```

which is better written as:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('select distinct %I, %I from %I', cola, colb, table_name);
```

Comment: Great! But can we use `select into` by using `EXECUTE`?

Comment: @Meem `EXECUTE ... INTO`. Please [read the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), it's all there.